# Can you disable Pylint inline messages in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Is there a way to disable inline Pylint (v2023.10.1) messages in Visual Studio Code (version 1.84.2 on [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11))? For example, I'm referring to "Formatting a regular string which could be an f-string" in the image below.

[image: Example Pylint inline message]

I work with a lot of legacy code and I can't fix every message. I like the squiggly blue line and the list of *problems*. But I find the text to be very distracting when there are a lot of messages.

Comment: That looks like [Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens). Is that it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Feel free to answer the question and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) extension.

The levels can be configured using:

```json
// settings.json
{
  "errorLens.enabledDiagnosticLevels": [
    "error",
    "warning",
    "info"
  ]
}
```

These three are the default values. Remove one or some of them as you please.

As an example, the following snippet triggers 3 types of notices:

[image: See answer source for transcription]

With `"info"` removed, it now looks like this:

[image: See answer source for transcription]